# ¿Cómo insertar HTML crudo en correos Gmail PHPMAILER?

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, gmail

Estoy realizando una validación de correo electrónico en lenguaje **PHP**, la cual la envío desde mi servidor local, al servidor de correos de GMAIL.

Mi código es:

```
$cuerpo = "Estimad@ $nombre: ";
$cuerpo .= "\r\n\r\n\t";
$cuerpo .= "Para completar el proceso de registro, favor realice la confirmación de Email.";
$cuerpo .= "\r\n\r\n\t";
$cuerpo .= "<button onclick=window.location.href=$url>Confirmar Email</button>";
$cuerpo .= "\r\n\r\n\r\n\t\t";
$cuerpo .= "Credenciales de Sesión:";
$cuerpo .= "\r\n\r\n\t\t\t";
$cuerpo .= "Username: $nombre";
$cuerpo .= "\r\n\t\t\t";
$cuerpo .= "Password: $password";
$cuerpo .= "\r\n\r\n\r\n\t";
$cuerpo .= "Si el link no funciona copie y pegue el siguiente enlace en su navegador: ";
$cuerpo .= "\r\n\r\n\t";
$cuerpo .= $url;
```

Así están llegando los correos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro hacer visible el botón HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu instancia de PHPMailer se llama *$mail*, asegurate de tener la siguiente línea de código:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

Por otra parte he leído que Button es un tag que se comporta diferente dependiendo del navegador que usas, en este caso el navegador que usa el cliente de correo con el que visualizas.

En su lugar pudieras probar con el tag INPUT o el viejo confiable tag A.

Checa esta pregunta en SO:

[Button vs Input Tag which to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

Es porque debes indicar que lo que envías es `HTML`

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


$headers .= 'To:' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Admin<youremail@email.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: me puedes ayudar a solucionarlo? reedite la publicación....

Comment: @Fede Lorca ¿has buscado ejemplos?  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial#using-html-email

Comment: Fede no coloques botón coloca un link `<a href="http://www.etc.com">Confirmar Email</a>`

Comment: @AlbertBarrientos pues no queda de otra al parecer.... gracias amigo